# Javascript event sequence, pg, postgresql, why?

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, express, pg

I am trying to write a javascript file in express to talk to a postgresql database.  More precisely, I want to write a function that takes SQL as an input parameter and returns the stringified json.  I can assume memory is not an issue given these table sizes.  This is paid work making an internal use tool for a private business.

My most recent attempt involved the query callback putting the value into a global variable, but even that still fails because the outermost function returns before the json string is defined.  Here is the relevant code:

```
var dbjson;

function callDB(q) {
    pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        } else {
            client.query(q, [], function(err, result) {
                client.query('COMMIT');
                done();
                if (err) {
                    console.error('error calling query ' + q, err);
                } else {
                    dbjson = JSON.stringify(result.rows);
                    console.log('1 ' + dbjson);
                }
                console.log('2 ' + dbjson);
            });
            console.log('3 ' + dbjson);
        }
        console.log('4 ' + dbjson);
    });
    console.log('5 ' + dbjson);
}
```

The SQL in my test is `"select id from users"`.
The relevant console output is:

```
5 undefined
GET /db/readTable?table=users 500 405.691 ms - 1671
3 undefined
4 undefined
1 [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]
2 [{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4}]
```

Why do the console logs occur in the order that they do?
They are consistent in the order.

I attempted to write a polling loop to wait for the global variable to be set using setTimeout in the caller and then clearing the timeout within the callback but that failed, I think, because javascript is single threaded and my loop did not allow other activity to proceed.  Perhaps I was doing that wrong.

While I know I could have each function handle its own database connection and error logging, I really hate repeating the same code.

What is a better way to do this?

I am relatively new to express and javascript but considerably more experienced with other languages.

Comment: I believe the console.logs occur in that order because both `pg.connect` and `client.query` are asynchronous.

Comment: Note the updated indentation of the code. All of your query/result handling is being done inside callback functions, which means `.connect()` fires, returns, and drops down to your `5`. then as things start happening, other parts of the code start running. e.g. all of this code is asynchronous.

Comment: *This is paid work making an internal use tool for a private business.*. Thanks for disclosing that, appreciated. I don't know enough about the JS side to explain this one I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank-you for the answers.  I believe that they are correct.  For anyone else who faces this problem, I worked around it by just repeating the call to the database in every function that needed it, sometimes multiple levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

Presence of the following line will break everything for you:

```
client.query('COMMIT');
```

You are trying to execute an asynchronous command in a synchronous manner, and you are calling `done()`, releasing the connection, before that query gets a chance to execute. The result of such invalid disconnection would be unpredictable, especially since you are not handling any error in that case.

And why are you calling a `COMMIT` there in the first place? That in itself looks completely invalid. `COMMIT` is used for closing the current transaction, that which you do not even open there, so it doesn't exist.

There is a bit of misunderstanding there in terms of asynchronous code usage and the database also. If you want to have a good start at both, I would suggest to have a look at [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).